# ImageUpload uploads twice (using AsyncFileUpload and AjaxControlToolkit)

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, image-uploading, asyncfileupload

I'm using `AsyncFileUpload` (AjaxControlToolkit) to upload images in a control. The problem is that the upload function (`AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedComplete`) runs on both the button click AND pageload, so it uploads the same image twice.

The code looks like this:

Front:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="asp" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" %>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function uploadComplete(sender, args) {
      var pathForUploadedImage = $('#uploadedHiddenField').val();
      $get("uploadImageImg").src = $('#uploadedHiddenField').val();
      $(".uploadImage").fadeIn(100);
    }
  </script>
  <asp:Image id="uploadImageImg" class="uploadImage" alt="" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
    <div id="uploadedImageDiv"></div>
    <asp:Image ID="loader" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/library/images/loading.gif" Style="display: None" />
    <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server" />
    <asp:AsyncFileUpload ID="AsyncFileUpload1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="asyncFileUpload" OnClientUploadComplete="uploadComplete" OnUploadedComplete="AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedComplete" CompleteBackColor="white" Width="65" />
    <asp:HiddenField ID="uploadedHiddenField" ClientIDMode="Static"  runat="server"/>
```

And back:

```
protected void AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e) {
  try {
    Styling.SetupStyles();
    string virualFolder = "";
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(UploadDirectory)) {
      virualFolder = "/" + Styling.GetStyleValue("customNewsImagesFolder", "") + "/";
    } else {
      virualFolder = "/" + Styling.GetStyleValue(UploadDirectory, "") + "/";
    }
    string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(e.FileName);
    int fileSize = Convert.ToInt32(e.FileSize);
    string physicalFolder = Server.MapPath(virualFolder);
    string randomFileName = System.IO.Path.GetRandomFileName().Replace(".", "");
    bool isUnique = true;
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(MapPath(virualFolder));
    FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();
    foreach (FileInfo myFile in files) {
      if (myFile.Name == randomFileName) {
        isUnique = false;
      }
    }
    IsAllowedFileExtension(fileExtension);
    bool error = false;
    if (!isUnique) {
      error = true;
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.GetType(), "tmp", "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('En fil med detta namn finns redan, var vänlig och döp om din fil');</script>", false);
    } else if (!IsAllowedMaxFileSize(fileSize)) {
      error = true;
      ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.GetType(), "tmp", "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Filen är för stor, vänligen försök igen med en fil som är mindre än 2 MB');</script>", false);
    } else if (!IsAllowedFileExtension(fileExtension)) {
      error = true;
      ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.GetType(), "tmp", "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Felaktigt filformat, vänligen försök igen med en fil av följande typ: .jpg .jpeg .png .gif');</script>", false);
    }
    if (!error) {
      AsyncFileUpload1.SaveAs(physicalFolder + randomFileName + fileExtension);
      string thePath = (virualFolder + randomFileName + fileExtension).Replace("\\", "/");
      ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "top.$get(\"" + uploadedHiddenField.ClientID + "\").value = '" + thePath + "';", true);
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex) {
    erLog.LogException(ex, System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
  }
}
private bool IsAllowedFileExtension(string fileExtension) {
  bool valid = false;
  if (fileExtension.ToLower() == ".jpg" || fileExtension.ToLower() == ".jpeg" || fileExtension.ToLower() == ".gif" || fileExtension.ToLower() == ".png")
    valid = true;
  return valid;
}
private bool IsAllowedMaxFileSize(int fileSize) {
  bool valid = false;
  if (fileSize < 2100000)
    valid = true;
  return valid;
}
```